# Showing whether the integral converges or not

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^5} dx$ is convergent.
My attempt:

Consider the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^{n^5}}$ . Then this series converges (by comparison test, comparing this series to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^{n}}$ .) Then by integral test given integral also converges. Am I correct?

Comment: The function is decreasing, so yes, you can use this test. Another way is simply to use the comparison test with $e^{-x^5}\leq e^{-x}$. This inequality holds for $x\geq 1$. (obviously in the interval $[0,1]$ there are no problems, so you just need to show the integral $\int_1^\infty$ converges)

Comment: Another common trick is to show that $e^{-x^5} \leq 1/x^5$ for all $x$, which should be quite obvious. Since the integral of latter converges, the former must converge. This method is sometimes easier if the function is complicated, and you can replace the upper bound with any function whose integral converges